# Lightsail Configure Apache's HTTP_HOST

Tags: php, lamp, bitnami, http-host, amazon-lightsail

I have an instance hosted using AWS Lightsail's LAMP stack. I also have a hostname on Godaddy.

$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] is returning 127.0.0.1:8000 where the application is running. Is there anyway to configure Apache so that this returns the hostname?

Comment: Edit the virtualhost config for the domain

Comment: I've added `ServerName example.com` and `UseCanonicalName On` under VirtualHost in my bitnami.conf, however $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 127.0.0.1:8000 and $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = localhost.

Comment: On this page: https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/faq/ I see that there is a FAQ for "How to configure the application's IP address or hostname?". Maybe this is necessary? : `sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/APPNAME/bnconfig --machine_hostname IP-ADDRESS`